# CSS- Select two input elements

Tags: css

[Demo of My Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/u840vdoz/1/)

I want to select first two input elements.

```
  .choicesDiv input[type="radio"]:nth-child(-n+2)
  {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
  }
```

Comment: You should be able to just use `.choicesDiv input[type="radio"]:nth-child(1), .choicesDiv input[type="radio"]:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your radio buttons in another element like a label, you can't apply a border directly to a radio button.

See below.

Also, if your intent is to actually set the border of a radio button then you'll need to look into creating custom radio buttons with something like this tutorial: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-895. It's relatively easy, all you're doing is hiding the radio button and setting the background image of a label to your custom radio button style.

```css
.qaDiv
{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 10px 0;
     border: 1px solid red;
}

.choicesDiv
{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.choicesDiv label:nth-child(-n+2)
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="qaDiv" index="">
    <div class="questionDiv">What is your name?</div>
    <div class="choicesDiv">
        <label><input type="radio" name="choices0" value="Gopi">Gopi</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="choices0" value="Gops">Gops</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="choices0" value="GopiNath">GopiNath</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="choices0" value="GopsAB">GopsAB</label>
    </div>
    <div class="answerDiv"></div>
    <div class="explanationToggle"></div>
    <div class="qButtons"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the radio type to checkbox. You can only select one radio button, whereas you can select multiple checkboxes

```css
.qaDiv
{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 10px 0;
     border: 1px solid red;
}

.choicesDiv
{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.choicesDiv input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(-n+2)
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="qaDiv" index="">
    <div class="questionDiv">What is your name?</div>
    <div class="choicesDiv">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices0" value="Gopi">Gopi
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices0" value="Gops">Gops
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices0" value="GopiNath">GopiNath
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices0" value="GopsAB">GopsAB
    </div>
    <div class="answerDiv"></div>
    <div class="explanationToggle"></div>
    <div class="qButtons"></div>
 </div>
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why border is not working, it's working with shadow

```
.choicesDiv input[type="radio"]:nth-child(-n+2)
{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 1px yellow;
}
```

Comment: You can't set the border of a radio button.

Comment: @AndyFurniss i know now, anyway thank you, box-shadow it's working good!